# Drive REST API use wifi only

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Previously, Google Drive API for Android was allowing to make a setting, that the data transfer was only done, when device is connected to the internet via WIFI:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/TransferPreferences.html#NETWORK_TYPE_WIFI_ONLY

This API will however become deprecated this year and we have to migrate to the new Drive REST API. I however struggle to find a similar functionality in this new API:

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/

Is setting NETWORK_TYPE_WIFI_ONLY not present anymore in this new Drive REST API?

Answer (score 0):

The Drive API for Android is being deprecated on 6th December 2019, the overview of which you can see on the [Drive API for Android pages](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation).

Check out the overview reference pages for drive in the [APIs for Android documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/package-summary) - there is no mention of the `TransferPreferences` interface being deprecated this December along with the other interfaces listed in the same table, and in fact is an interface that replaced the deprecated `FileUploadPreferences` interface.

Comment: Aren't they going to depreciated the whole com.google.android.gms.drive package? Also, even if TransferPreferences is not marked depreciated, it is not clear how one can use them with new API. With old API one would set them to DriveClient: DriveClient.setUploadPreferences(prefs). But DriveClient itself is now depreciated: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveClient